# Ajax/PHP contact form blank fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello I have made a contact form on my website but when the user type in the details and submit the form, it sends some blank information and cannot find why. Also, a major issue, the form changes the name field for the countries one, so it came in like "Name: France" instead of "Name: John".

I have also added form validator from here https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator. Anyone know why this is happening? 
Below are the js, the php and the html.

```js
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Something went wrong! Did you fill in the form properly?");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});


function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
 var last = $("#last").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
 var company = $("#company").val();
 var users = $("#users").val();
 var country = $("#country").val();
    var msg_subject = $("#msg_subject").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "assets/php/form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&last=" + last + "&email=" + email + "&company=" + company + "&users=" + users + "&country=" + country + "&msg_subject=" + msg_subject + "&message=" + message,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Message Submitted!")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

```css
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// LAST NAME
if (empty($_POST["last"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Last name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["last"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

// COMPANY
if (empty($_POST["company"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Company name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["company"];
}

// USERS
if (empty($_POST["users"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Users number is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["users"];
}

// COUNTRY
if (empty($_POST["country"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Country is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["country"];
}

// MSG SUBJECT
if (empty($_POST["msg_subject"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Subject is required ";
} else {
    $msg_subject = $_POST["msg_subject"];
}


// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
}


$EmailTo = "info@email.com";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Last: ";
$Body .= $last;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Company: ";
$Body .= $company;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Users: ";
$Body .= $users;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Country: ";
$Body .= $country;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Subject: ";
$Body .= $msg_subject;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Something went wrong :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

```html
<html>  
<form id="contactForm" class="contact-form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">First name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required data-error="Please enter your First name">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only">Last name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="last" id="last" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required data-error="Please enter your Last name">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of /.row -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" required data-error="Please enter your Email address">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only">Company</label>
                        <input type="text" name="company" id="company" class="form-control" placeholder="Company" required data-error="Please enter your Company name">
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Users" class="sr-only legacy-label">Users</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="users" input name="users" required data-error="Please select the User Number">
                                    <option value="">Users Number</option>
                                    <option value="1 - 3">1 - 3</option>
                                    <option value="4 - 7">4 - 7</option>
                                    <option value="8 - 12">8 - 12</option>
                                    <option value="More than 13">More than 13</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Country" class="sr-only legacy-label">Country</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="country" input name="country" required data-error="Please select your Country">
                                    <option value="">Select your country</option>
                                    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                                    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                                    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                                    <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                                    <option value="And so on...">And so on...</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of /.row -->
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only">Subject</label>
                            <input type="text" name="msg_subject" id="msg_subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required data-error="Please enter your Subject">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only">Your Message</label>
                                <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Your Message" required data-error="Please enter your Message"></textarea>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-base-alt btn-cmd">Send Message</button>
                    </form>
     </html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your problem is the variable attribution, each input should have is own variable

You make

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
...
$name = $_POST["last"];
...
$name = $_POST["company"];
...
$name = $_POST["users"];
...
$name = $_POST["country"];
```

You should have

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
...
$last = $_POST["last"];
...
$company = $_POST["company"];
...
$users = $_POST["users"];
...
$country = $_POST["country"];
```

The last attribution is the country, that why you have

> Name: France" instead of "Name: John"

Comment: Thank you so much @olibiaz! You saved my day :)

Comment: You welcome, mark the question as answered please.

Comment: Done! Thank you again!